# Why Do I Need to Cast Int To A Double Variable In A Print Statement If Its Already Declared/Initialized As A Double?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, casting

I am trying to traverse an array in Java via a for loop, but for some reason it will only print the doubles in my list if I cast 'int'. Otherwise I get a "Type Mismatch: cannot convert double to int" even though everything is a double and I never once attempt to convert any number to an int. I am a complete begginer to programming, so any and all help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
package MyProgram1;
import cs1.Keyboard;

public class MyProgram1{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        double [] array = {1.0,2.0,4.0,2.5,5.0};
        for (double index = 0.0; index <= array.length-1.0; index++){
                        \\The line below is what results in the error
            System.out.println(array[index]);
                        }
    
    }
}
```

I saw a suggestion (in eclipse) that said "add cast to int" and here is what that looks like:

```
package MyProgram1;
import cs1.Keyboard;

public class MyProgram1{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double [] array1 = {1.0,2.0,4.0,2.5,5.0};
        for (double index = 0.0; index <= array1.length-1.0; index++)
            System.out.println(array1[(int)index]);

            
    
    }
}
```

Works perfectly and what prints is the following:

```
1.0
2.0
4.0
2.5
5.0
```

My question is why? Why do I need to cast it, and when I do, why is everything printed as a double? Shouldn't the results be integers?

Again, any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: values in array are doubles, but index is not double - index in array is integer

Comment: That the error was inside a "print statement" is irrelevant. It would have occurred anywhere there was an attempt to use a `double` as an array index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating over your array with "double" variable. Array indices are of *integer* type

Change your "index" variable type to int and it should be fine i.e.,

```java
public static void main(String[] args){

    double [] array = {1.0,2.0,4.0,2.5,5.0};
    for (int index = 0; index <= array.length-1; index++){
        System.out.println(array[index]);
  }
}
```

There are other ways to iterate over array as well. HEre is one where you don't need special index. rather you need a variable (of the same type as array) to hold the value i.e.,

```
    for (double val : array) {
      System.out.println(val);
    }
```